# Trying to join two text files based on the first column in both files and want to keep all the columns of the matches from the second file

Tags: awk, comm

I'm trying to join two text files based on their first columns and where those columns are the same I want to keep all the columns from the second file.

```
List1.txt
action
adan
adap
adapka
adat
yen


List2.txt
action  e KK SS @ n
adham   a d h a m
adidas  a d i d a s
administration  e d m i n i s t r e SS @ n
administrative  e d m i n i s t r e t i v
admiral e d m aj r @ l
adnan   a d n a n
ado     a d o
adan    a d @ n
adap    a d a p
adapka  a d a p k a
adrenalin       @ d r e n @ l i n
adrian  a d r j a n
adat    a d a t
adtec   e d t e k
adult   @ d a l t
yen     j e n
```

I'd like to get everything from `list1.txt` that matches `list2.txt` plus all the other columns in `list2.txt`.  `List3.txt` should look like this.

```
List3.txt
action  e KK SS @ n
adan    a d @ n
adap    a d a p
adapka  a d a p k a
adat    a d a t
yen     j e n
```

I've tried the following command from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37170326/bash-comm-command-but-for-multiple-columns):

```
$awk -F: 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next}{if($1 in a){print a[$1];} else {print;}}'  List1.txt List2.txt > List3.txt
```

I've also tried this:

```
$comm <(sort List2.txt) <(sort List1.txt)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there are ways to do this is awk, but join is also relatively simple.

```
join -1 1 -2 1 List1.txt <(sort -k 1,1 List2.txt) > List3.txt
```

You are joining `List1` based on the first column, and joining `List2` also based on the first column. You then need to make sure the files are sorted in alphabetical order so join can work.

This produces the columns you want, separated by a whitespace.

```
List3.txt
action e KK SS @ n
adan a d @ n
adap a d a p
adapka a d a p k a
adat a d a t
yen j e n
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way to accomplish what you are attempting is with `grep` using the values in `List1.txt` to match as *fixed-string* the content in `List2.txt` redirecting the result to `List3.txt`, e.g.

```
grep -Ff List1.txt List2.txt > List3.txt
```

If using GNU `grep` or with `-w, --word-regex` available adding `-w` ensures only a whole-word match, e.g.

```
grep -Fwf List1.txt List2.txt > List3.txt
```

**Resulting List3.txt**

```
$ cat List3.txt
action  e KK SS @ n
adan    a d @ n
adap    a d a p
adapka  a d a p k a
adat    a d a t
yen     j e n
```

(**note:** all whitespace is preserved in `List3.txt`)

Comment: I'd add `-w` to the grep options (Assuming gnu grep) so that only whole words match, not prefixes too (Try yours with adapka removed from List1.txt).